# CSS - want to remove a blank space but have no idea how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

OK so here is my code, I don't understand why the first blank space is appearing to the left hand side of the page.

**CSS**

```
.header-left ol{
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #6899D3;      
}

.header-left li{
    list-style:none;
float:left;
}

.header-left a {
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;               
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.header-left a:hover {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav1 a:hover { background-color: #FF5B0D; }    

#nav2  a:hover {    background-color:#00FF40;}

#nav3  a:hover {    background-color:#FF0080;}

#nav4  a:hover {    background-color:#00CCFF;}

#nav5  a:hover { background-color: #FFFF00; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-left">
  <ol>
    <li id="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">a</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="http://www.google.com">b</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="http://www.google.com">c</a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="http://www.google.com">d</a></li> 
    <li id="nav5"><a href="http://www.google.com">e</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Right click on any list entry and select 'inspect' (this is available at least in Firefox), then check the box model for any margins/borders/paddings and figure out where they are, then remove them via CSS. Or simply add a global `*{padding:0;margin:0;border:0;}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the natural `padding` and `margin` of the `body` and `ol`. Set:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header-left ol{
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #6899D3;        
    margin: 0; //RESET DEFAULT
    padding: 0; // RESET DEFAULT
}
```

Comment: @user3155620 This is a bit overkill, the only thing that needs setting to `0` is `padding-left` on the `ol`, as indicated in j08691's and Samleo's answers.

Comment: @ajp15243 resetting the padding and margin on the body is good practice. If you use a file like normalize.css it will do that for you as well as reset the defaults applied to elements like `h1`, `ol`, etc.

Comment: @jmore009 Resetting `body`'s I can see in the majority of cases, but all the other elements I would hesitate on making a blanket statement that resetting everything is always good. It depends on your application. Exact positioning of everything might not be a necessary goal, so slightly different values between user agent stylesheets might not matter, and having them might actually save a lot of excessive work of putting `margin`/`padding` on everything that would sensibly have something there.

Comment: personal preference i guess but I wouldn't call it overkill. I like to have control of the padding and margin, it allows for it to be more consistent across browsers

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left:0;` to your `.header-left ol` rules.

```
.header-left ol {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: #6899D3;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nT48p/)**

Comment: This still leaves a gap between the left side of the blue `ol` box and the left edge of the page (at least in Chrome), due to user-agent `margin` styles on `body`.

Comment: @ajp15243 - true, however the way I read the question the OP is concerned with the large gap next to the first item, not the extra space next to the list.

Comment: Ah, apparently I'm blind, did not notice that when I first plugged the code into jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to that is because u are using `<ol><li></li></ol>` which by default has a left padding. Even if you set list-type:none, you are not getting rid of the left padding. Instead, in the ol code block set `padding:0;` or `padding-left:0` like this:

```
.header-left ol{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-color: #6899D3;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your margin try putting in something like this as this will drag it up and pull the bottom up

This is to be put in your styles CSS sheet

```
margin: -30px 0px -30px 0px;
```